# How can I implement a queue of animations that occur one after the other is over

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uiviewanimation

So here is what I am trying to do, I want there to be a queue of animations that occur. These cannot occur simualtaneously, because that would ruin the effect and only show the last animation in the queue. How can I create a queue that waits for the previous animation to complete before starting a new one (in Swift)?

The following shows only the final animation in the array of xpItems.

```
            var xpItems = XPItem.loadCustomObjectWithKey()
            for (var i = 0; i < xpItems.count; i++) { //for each XP Item.
                let rewardName = xpItems[i].title
                let rewardAmount = xpItems[i].xpAmount
                println(rewardName + " " + String(rewardAmount))

                let currentLevelXPRequired = 100
                let newProgress = CGFloat(rewardAmount) / CGFloat(currentLevelXPRequired) as CGFloat

                self.xpCircle.setProgress(xpCircle.progress + newProgress, animated: true)

            }
```

//Rest of the code is Obj-c.

```
- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.progress == progress) {
        return;
    }
    if (animated == NO) {
        if (_displayLink) {
            //Kill running animations
            [_displayLink removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
            _displayLink = nil;
        }
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    } else {
        _animationStartTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
        _animationFromValue = self.progress;
        _animationToValue = progress;
        if (!_displayLink) {
            //Create and setup the display link
            [self.displayLink removeFromRunLoop:NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
            self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animateProgress:)];
            [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        } /*else {
            //Reuse the current display link
        }*/
    }
}


- (void)animateProgress:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGFloat dt = (displayLink.timestamp - _animationStartTime) / self.animationDuration;
        if (dt >= 1.0) {
            //Order is important! Otherwise concurrency will cause errors, because setProgress: will detect an animation in progress and try to stop it by itself. Once over one, set to actual progress amount. Animation is over.
            [self.displayLink removeFromRunLoop:NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
            self.displayLink = nil;
            [super setProgress:_animationToValue animated:NO];
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
            return;
        }

        //Set progress
        [super setProgress:_animationFromValue + dt * (_animationToValue - _animationFromValue) animated:YES];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

    });
}
```

The super.setProgress[..]:

```
- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    _progress = progress;
}
```

Sorry about having the code be in obj-c/swift.

Comment: Use recursion concept.

Comment: I think you can try using operation queue and set concurrency to 1 and define the logic to dequeue one animation after the other

Comment: Could you provide an example? Thanks

Comment: @Dinakar Could you provide an example?

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel here. I would NOT do frame-based animation using a CADisplayLink. That's the maximum amount of work, and also likely to give the worst performance with the most CPU cost. Use UIView block animations, as RASS suggests, or CAAnimation objects. I

Comment: I have even seen third party solutions that let you create an array of block animations and submit them for playing in order.  You might look into one of those if RASS' (excellent) solution doesn't meet your need

Answer (score 4):

Most animation methods, certainly in UIKit have a completion handler that is optionally called when the animation is complete. All you need to do is create an array of `UIView`s or some other object that you can then perform an animation on (maybe an array of `CGPoint`s), then just animate through all the objects in order. E.g:

```
- (void)animateArrayWithCompletion:(void(^)(void))handler
{
    if (!viewArray.count) {
        if (handler) {
            handler();
        }
    }
    else {
        UIView *myView = viewArray.lastObject;
        [viewArray removeObject:myView];
        CGRect frame = myView.frame;
        frame.origin.x += 100;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            myView.frame = frame;
        } completion:^(BOOL complete) {
            [self animateArrayWithCompletion:handler];
        }];   
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this alot! Thanks